# Window opened via psexec is blank when using PowerShell Direct, but is OK when psexec starts locally

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, psexec

I am trying to build a simple environment to take screenshots automatically. I have several Hyper-V VMs and I need to use PowerShell Direct to run commands on them in a special sequence. When I run `psexec` to open `notepad.exe` via PowerShell Direct, Notepad's window opens, but it is blank. I can blindly click controls on the window (e.g., on the toolbar) and it appears that they work, but nothing is actually displayed besides a blank window.

The only simple option to open Windows in an existing session I see now is to run `psexec` (any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated because my attempts to stick to PowerShell-only approach hits a roadblock, see [Starting a GUI application on a guest VM with PowerShell Direct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62476454/761095)).

I run `psexec` on one of the virtual machines to start `notepad.exe` in session 2. This PowerShell snippet runs on a host VM, it contacts guest VM via PowerShell Direct.

```
Invoke-Command  -VMName 'client1.example.com' -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
C:\bin\psexec.exe \\client1.example.com -i 2 "notepad.exe"
}
```

`notepad.exe` starts, but the window is blank. Is this a bug in `psexec`?

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

The problem does not occur when I run `psexec` directly in a guest VM.

```
C:\bin\psexec.exe \\client1.example.com -i 2 "notepad.exe"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding the `-s` option. I don't understand why the problem occurs in the first place and how running it "in the system account" helps.

> `-s   Run the remote process in the System account.`

The problem does not occur when I start `explorer.exe`, BTW.